# How to know which answer was upvoted on a post where I have multiple answers?

Tags: support, answers, reputation, activity-tab

The 'reputation' label, on my 'activity' page says that I received an upvote on question X, but I have more than one valid answer on this question. How can I know which one received the upvote?

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795815/how-to-make-right-side-of-page-scroll-and-left-side-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the link on the Reputation tab, it will take you to the associated upvoted post.

You can use the same procedure from the notification bar at the top too. When you are notified of reputation changes, if you click on the notice and then the associated post, you'll be taken directly to the one that received an upvote.